# Loading Values of a JSON to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I cant find what is wrong with the code listed below. It is not loading the values of values.json into the variable statesau. If I      document.write(JSON.stringify(statesau)) I get {}

The content of values.json is

```
{
"values": {
    "New South Wales": 8,
    "Victoria": 6,
    "Queensland": 3,
    "South Australia": 7,
    "Western Australia": 4,
    "Tasmania": 6,
    "Northern Territory": 7
}
}
```

The HTML code is here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Wave to GeoJSON</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
#states path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Wave to GeoJSON</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var statesau={};
  $.getJSON('values.json', function(data) {
    statesau=data;
  });
  document.write(JSON.stringify(statesau));
var w = 960,
    h = 500;
var z = d3.scale.category10();
var fill = d3.scale.log()
    .domain(d3.extent(d3.values(statesau)))
    .range(["brown", "steelblue"]);
var projection = d3.geo.azimuthal()
    .origin([135, -26])
  .translate([250,180])
    .scale(700);
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);
var states = svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "states");
d3.json("au-states.json", function(collection) {
  states.selectAll("path")
      .data(collection.features)
    .enter().append("path")
   .attr("fill", function(d) {
         return fill(statesau[(d.properties["STATE_NAME"])]);
       })
      .attr("d", path);
});
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the function in `getJSON` will async.. this means its not available for `document.write`

Comment: So if I wanted to view the contents on a page - what code would I use? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you have asynchronous function like `getJSON`, you need to restructure your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Wave to GeoJSON</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
#states path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Wave to GeoJSON</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var statesau={};
          $.getJSON('values.json', function(data) {
            statesau=data;
            restOfCode();
          });
          function restOfCode(){
                  document.write(JSON.stringify(statesau));
                var w = 960,
                    h = 500;
                var z = d3.scale.category10();
                var fill = d3.scale.log()
                    .domain(d3.extent(d3.values(statesau)))
                    .range(["brown", "steelblue"]);
                var projection = d3.geo.azimuthal()
                    .origin([135, -26])
                        .translate([250,180])
                    .scale(700);
                var path = d3.geo.path()
                    .projection(projection);
                var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);
                var states = svg.append("g")
                    .attr("id", "states");
                d3.json("au-states.json", function(collection) {
                  states.selectAll("path")
                      .data(collection.features)
                    .enter().append("path")
                            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                         return fill(statesau[(d.properties["STATE_NAME"])]);
                       })
                      .attr("d", path);
                });
            }
        </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that, as [webdeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5004923/webdeb) mentioned in his comment, `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous function. If you want document.write to function properly, it will have to be added to the callback like so:

```
$.getJSON('values.json', function(data) {
  statesau=data;
  document.write(JSON.stringify(statesau));
});
```

Comment: [SoftwareEngineer171 gives a more thorough answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38382853/6590624).